# Powershell csv upload to SQL Server database - how to generate a unique key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a Powershell script that generates a `.CSV` file of computer's WMI information, Then the script uploads it to a SQL Server database.

How can I get the SQL Server database to create a unique key and keep the same primary key on each upload?

Answer (score 2):

you may use an `IDENTITY` column. the `IDENTITY` column generates an auto-number for every insert on the table. check this sql fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9128/1

Comment: Thanks.  will it also keep the same ID when the record updates

Comment: yes. the `IDENTITY` column of a table is not updatable but can be manually inserted with a value, if the need arises, using `SET IDENTITY INSERT MyUploadTable ON`. be sure to execute `SET IDENTITY INSERT MyUploadTable OFF` after you manually insert the value for the ID column.